# Neo4j query very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can not understand why this cypher query is very slow, despite the fact it is very simple. However, it is fast in the neo4j browser. The execution time is 13973ms.

```
String cql = "MATCH (p:Protocole) --> (i:Instance) where p.nomProtocole = 'gestion des commandes'  "
             + "AND i.activitéEnCours = 'Inscription du client'  AND i.situation = 'Active' "
             + "RETURN i.activitéEnCours, p.nomProtocole, i.instID, i.situation, i.timeStamp";

long start1= System.currentTimeMillis();
Result result = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("BDDGBPM")).execute(cql);
long end1= System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("ExecutionResult time:"+ (end1-start1));
```

Comment: do you have schema indexes set up ? http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/

Comment: In the time you're counting, you are spinning up a new embedded database. Please do this outside of your benchmark ;-)